# Programatic way to send parameters in AWS Batch job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-batch

How to invoke an AWS batch python job from a python script (possibly boto) with additional parameters.

Also from the batch side how the additional parameters will be fetched?

Comment: Do you know how to do it in console? Can you provide an example what you mean and what should be translated to boto3?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`submit_job()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/batch.html#Batch.Client.submit_job) documentation? It accepts a `parameters` field.